# Castor unmarshalling auto named primitive types

Tags: java, xml, castor

First of all, please excuse my poor English

Can you please advice how I can unmarshal following XML structure:

```
<elements>
    <element>
        <long>1</long>
    </element>
    <element>
        <string>Test</string>
    </element>
    <element>
        <long>5</long>
    </element>
</elements>
```

where long, string - basic JAVA types.

Here is how each "element" is described for marshaling:

```
<class
    name="com.test.MessageElement"
    verify-constructable="false">

    <field name="element">
        <bind-xml auto-naming="deriveByClass" />
    </field>

</class>
```

Thank you in advance